# How to configure multiple SP for a single IdP

Tags: php, simplesamlphp

I've been following along this tutorial:

http://www.worldgoneweb.com/2013/installing-simplesamlphp-and-use-it-as-sp-and-idp-for-development-env-only/

.... it has really helped to setup authentication between SP and IdP. However, when configuring the metadata/saml20-remote-sp.php file it tells me to copy and paste the contents of a box (SP: Federation > Show metadata > simpleSAMLphp flat file format box) to that file. I've done this, and it works great for a single SP - I just don't really know how to add another SP. I checked the documentation but it only shows minimum set required, and no mention/example of multiple SPs.

Below is my IdP's metadata/saml20-remote-sp.php with a single SP:

```
$metadata['http://local-ssoidp'] = array (
  'SingleLogoutService' =>
  array (
    0 =>
    array (
      'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect',
      'Location' => 'http://local-mwqasys/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-logout.php/default-sp',
    ),
  ),
  'AssertionConsumerService' =>
  array (
    0 =>
    array (
      'index' => 0,
      'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST',
      'Location' => 'http://local-mwqasys/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/default-sp',
    ),
    1 =>
    array (
      'index' => 1,
      'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:profiles:browser-post',
      'Location' => 'http://local-mwqasys/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml1-acs.php/default-sp',
    ),
    2 =>
    array (
      'index' => 2,
      'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Artifact',
      'Location' => 'http://local-mwqasys/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml2-acs.php/default-sp',
    ),
    3 =>
    array (
      'index' => 3,
      'Binding' => 'urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:profiles:artifact-01',
      'Location' => 'http://local-mwqasys/simplesaml/module.php/saml/sp/saml1-acs.php/default-sp/artifact',
    ),
  ),
);
```

How can I add additional SPs to this? I considered merging the arrays together (arrays given from each SP's show metadata page) but want to gain a little better understanding other than guesswork. Can anyone please advise on how this is done. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a second SP under your first one.

So copy what you currently have and paste it at the bottom of the file. Then edit the second copy with the details of your second SP.

Cheers